# calculate score for missing days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have below history table :

```
Create table st_scorehist (stid int , compdate date , compscore decimal(18,4))

Insert into st_scorehist 
 values(1333 , '2014-07-06', 3.2),
(1333, '2014-07-08',3.6),
(1333, '2014-07-09',3.1),
(1333, '2014-07-13',3.9),
(1337, '2014-07-07',5.9),
(1337, '2014-07-08',5.7),
(1337, '2014-07-11',5.2),
(1337, '2014-07-14',5.3)
```

This table gets populated daily only for users whose compscore is changed from previous score. For example, if score for stid 1333 didn't change on July 7th then we ignore this user hence the gaps in history table.

Now requirement is to generate report based on passed date values . If score is not available for user for any date then we need to populate compscore from previous day for that user.For instance, if the query was run on July 14th then here is the needed output.

```
stid    compdate    compscore
1333    7/6/2014    3.2
1333    7/7/2014    3.2
1333    7/8/2014    3.6
1333    7/9/2014    3.1
1333    7/10/2014   3.1
1333    7/11/2014   3.1
1333    7/12/2014   3.1
1333    7/13/2014   3.9
1333    7/14/2014   3.9
1337    7/6/2014    NULL
1337    7/7/2014    5.9
1337    7/8/2014    5.7
1337    7/9/2014    5.7
1337    7/10/2014   5.7
1337    7/11/2014   5.2
1337    7/12/2014   5.2
1337    7/13/2014   5.2
1337    7/14/2014   5.3
```

I was thinking of left joining calender table to generate this data but since we need it per stid so it becomes quite challenging.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
NJ

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the dates for each `stid` using a recursive CTE.  Then you can then use `left join` to fill in the values:

```
with dates as (
      select stid, min(compdate) as thedate, max(compdate) as maxcd
      from st_scorehist
      group by stid
      union all
      select stid, dateadd(day, 1, thedate), maxcd
      from dates
      where thedate < maxcd
)
select dates.stid, dates.thedate as compdate,
       coalesce(compscore, 0) as compscore
from dates left outer join
     st_scorehist sh
     on sh.compdate = dates.thedate and sh.stid = dates.stid;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6954/12) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The LEFT JOIN based on a calendar table is the right approach. But you'll also have to do a cross join against distinct stid and then perform a left join of this result set against st_scorehist based on stid and compdate.